# Why does Linux server close after i do password reset

Tags: linux

I login Linux server. It asks me forcefully for password reset. After i do password reset the server close. I don't want this to happen. What do i need to do so that server doesn't close?

Comment: Don't set the root password to reset when you install the OS

Answer (score 0):

Your password is probably set with an expiration date.  Do "chage -l username" to see if/when your password expires.  You can use "chage -E -1 -M -1" to remove the expiry altogether.